# Post image with facebook

Tags: android, facebook

How can I post an image from either drawable resource or from a link?

I tried

```
 byte[] data = null;
 BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 opts.inSampleSize=4;           
 Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.badge);
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 data = baos.toByteArray();

 params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

But this is not doing anything. The image is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
 params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
 params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
 params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
 params.putString("picture","ImageURL");// for image
 params.putString("name",getString(R.string.app_action));
```

for more details [How to allow user to post an Image on Wall using SDCard Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657388/how-to-allow-user-to-post-an-image-on-wall-using-sdcard-folder/18657604?noredirect=1#comment27498125_18657604)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207559/2003486). There are two ways to post image on facebook. One to share on wall through link and another to upload as a byte array in facebook album.